# Laravel 4 - Login count using standard authentication

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction.

I have just started using laravel 4 and i want to add a login count to my application.

Im using the standard authentication from the laravel docs.

Im guess that i have to add something like the following SQL ... But do i add it from the routes file or the User.php model ... and then how would i call it from the login route?

```
$sql = "UPDATE some_table SET total_logins = total_logins + 1 WHERE user_id = $userID";
```

Any help would be awesome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, instead of sql, i would use Eloquent.

Then, you can access your logged in user with the `Auth::user()` function, and use Eloquent increment function :

```
Auth::user()->increment('total_logins');
Auth::user()->save();
```

I would do that in your login function in your UserController file.

```
if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password)))
{
    Auth::user()->increment('total_logins');
    Auth::user()->save();
}
```

Comment: Really ... Its as simple as that? ... Awesome... Thank you